# Intellij 10.5.4 replaces iml files' libary root url localvariable with $USER_HOME$

Tags: class, url, variables, maven, intellij-idea

for some reason when I reopen my intellij projects, the iml files’ root tags’ url parameter is automatically replacing my user-defined local variable with $USER_HOME$.

Furthermore, when I go in and manually replace (with CTRL+R) the $USER_HOME$ with the $LOCAL_VAR$, Intellij replaces this change with $LOCAL_VAR$/.m2/repository.  Have you ever run into this issue?

code from one of the directory .iml files:

```
<library> 
<classes> 
<root url="jar://$LOCAL_VAR$/.m2/repository/.m2/repository/bar/foo.jar!/" />
</classes> 
<JAVADOC/> 
</libarary>
```

When I go and replace the $LOCAL_VAR$/.m2/repository with $LOCAL_VAR$ for the second time, no further autoreplacements occur.  The reason why I need to replace $USER_HOME$ with $LOCAL_VAR$ is because $USER_HOME$ is system-defined, and I need to point my code to a SAMBA drive that I've mounted onto my Windows7 pc.

If you can please suggest either a way to override my $USER_HOME$ or a possible cause of this odd behavior, I would be grateful for your wisdom.  Please note that when I originally imported this project, I had generated the .iml files from a .ipr file.  Not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define /.m2/repository/ as a separate path variable, this one should not be overridden.